# Pushing a folder containing my back-end folder and my front-end folder

Tags: github, frontend, backend, commit

I have 2 folders, 1 for my backend code and the other for my frontend code. Each one has its own .git.
Is It possible to push to GitHub a folder containing both backend and frontend folders without losing the commits i made in both folders ?

The only answer i read was deleting the .git file in both folders but it say that it will delete all the commits i made.